Groovy MapConstructor does not instanciate sub list with correct type
i'm having an issue using the @MapConstructor given by groovy.
Given this kind of payload body
// @no-cookie-jar
// @no-log
POST {{host}}/api/collection?logon={{logon}}&key={{key}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "libelle": "{{$random.alphanumeric(25)}}",
  "collaborators": [{ "utilisateur": 1001 }, { "utilisateur": 1003 }]
}

which is processed like this in a generic class somewhere in my codebase :
def payload = new JsonSlurper(type: JsonParserType.INDEX_OVERLAY).parse(body, "UTF-8")
// dtoKlass is CollectionDto
def dto = dtoKlass.newInstance(payload) as DTO

And here are the 2 POJOs
@MapConstructor
class UtilisateurLightDto {
    long utilisateur
}

@MapConstructor
class CollectionDto {
    long collection
    String libelle

    List<UtilisateurLightDto> collaborators = []
}

Everything was great until I added the collaborators field to CollectionDto. When the resulting object from the newInstance is returned, collaborators is not typed as expected (ie: List<UtilisateurLightDto> )

Do you know if this is possible ? should I create my own Constructor to deal with this ?
Thanks

could you please elaborate on expected expect result and the actual result

TL;DR: this can not work.  Use a proper library for (de)serializing data
to objects (e.g. Jackson also can go directly from/to JSON)
You can get from Map to T, but you can not get from List<Map> to
List<T> with coercion and MapConstructor.
The target type is List (see why not more
What is the concept of erasure in generics in Java?).
And the input is something list-ish… good enough, take it.
If there where no List but just UtilisateurLightDto it would work,
because Groovy will coerce the map-ish object to the object needed.
This is the best you can get.
Another problem using @MapConstructor is that it want to use every key
of the map, so it will throw, if your map has more/other keys, that are
not
